# Page replacement algorithm simulation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, replace

Is there utility program for Page replacement algorithm simulation in Java?

Comment: Are you talking about OS page replacement algorithms ?

Comment: Please be more concrete. Why do you need this algo to be implemented? Where are you going to use it?

Comment: -1 voting to close as too vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I developed-

https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=5924&lngWId=2

Check out it

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Java abstracts away the concrete memory management, so there should seldom be a need for this.

**Edit:**

Think some more seconds. No, there is no such algorithm in the standart libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 'Page replacement' as in virtual memory management, I cannot see there would be something like that. I mean the JVM does a lot of work to hide that from developers and provide a consistent memory model (with varying degrees of success).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to experiment with different algorithms and learn how they work, then you may want to have a look at [custard-cache](http://code.google.com/p/custard-cache/) -- this is an embryonic open-source implementation of some of the most common page replacement algorithms, along with an adapter for those algorithms to be used in JBoss Cache and a very small test suite to let you run different cache algorithms over our own sample data to judge hit ratio + effectiveness.

Now, a **disclaimer**: *I wrote it this code*. It was developed as an experimental exercise at my employer, where we were trying to maximise the efficacy of a cache and wanted to know if a different algorithm would help us. We didn't end up changing algorithms, but we figured someone else might have a use for it so open-sourced it. Nothing much has been done with it since but please take a look and see if it's useful.

Paging algorithms implemented are:

- Direct-mapped (associative)
- FIFO
- LRU
- LFU
- [Adaptive Replacement Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_replacement_cache) (and Fixed Replacement Cache)
- [Multi-Queue Replacement](http://www.usenix.org/event/usenix01/full_papers/zhou/zhou_html/index.html)
- Johnson and Shasha's 2Q algorithm

There are others I'd like to implement (the Clock family, LRU-K, CAR) but haven't got around to it.

Hope it's helpful!